# Class 'app\login' not found in laravel 5.8

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.8, laravel-controller

I am using laravel 5.8 and have an issue with model class. Since model is placed directly in app folder.

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Login extends Model
{
    //
}
```

In Controller, I am using

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use app\Login;
use DB;
```

I initialized model class object in MyController.php as

```
$table_ob=new Login;
```

but facing this issue "Class 'app\Login' not found" when i submit form to controller.

Comment: `App\Login` vs. `app\Login`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's minor spell mistake

```
use app\Login;
```

**to**

```
use App\Login;
```

Comment: Spelling mistakes can be answered in a comment and vote for issues to be closed. It won't help anyone else.

Comment: thanks @nakov but it's perfect answer of his question so that I give in answer :)